# Longitudinal Multilevel Model of unbalanced data

Tags: r, mlm

I'm doing a longitudinal multilevel model analysis of change to look at the impact racism has on health.

My level 2 is thus individual, while my level 1 is time/wave.

I'm using 5 different waves of the UKHLS and in order to include more people I decided to use an unbalanced dataset as every book I read said that MLM can handle that without a problem. However now while trying to fit even one of the simplest models I'm already encountering a problem getting an error message. This is my code and the error message I receive:

> m1 <- lmer(data = lusl, generalhealth ~ 1 + wave0 +(1 + wave0 | pidp),
> na.action=na.exclude)
>
> Error: number of observations (=30962) <= number
> of random effects (=31520) for term (1 + wave0 | pidp); the
> random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale
> parameter) are probably unidentifiable

Is there anything I can do about this?

Edited to add: After some more googling I found this code as a solution:

> m1 <- lmer(data = lusl, generalhealth ~ 1 + wave0 +(1 + wave0 | pidp),
> control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "warning"))
>
> Warning messages: 1: number of observations (=30962) <= number of
> random effects (=31520) for term (1 + wave0 | pidp); the
> random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale
> parameter) are probably unidentifiable  2: In checkConv(attr(opt,
> "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :   Model failed to
> converge with max|grad| = 0.0109117 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

So whilst I get these warning messages, I do get an output now. Unfortunately, I don't really understand the warning message or what that control function does so I'm not sure if I should use it? Could anyone explain to me what it does?

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it will be difficult for us to help.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to provide that. When I use dput(mydataset) the output is huge so that I couldn't copy it all. Any advice?

Comment: How about a subset of individuals, say using the first 25 unique values of `pidp`?

Comment: Do you know a code for this in R?

Comment: `dput(subset(lusl, pidp %in% unique(pidp)[1:25]))`